# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function error message

Tags: php, function, oop

**UPDATE 1:**

I forgot to add `GetTags()` method, so here it is:

```
public $blog_tags;
public function GetTags()
{
    return $this->blog_tags;
}
```

=========================================================================

I'm working with PHP OOP to develop my project. Basically I have a table called `blogs` which contains some fields and data like this image:

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m98Zn.png)

Then I created a class `Blos.class.php` and made two methods as below:

```
public function ShowTag()
{
    $tag = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT blog_tags FROM blogs");
    $tag->execute();
    while($row = $tag->fetch())
    {
        $this->blog_tags = $row['blog_tags'];
    }
}
public function NumTag()
{
    $cat = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT blog_tags FROM blogs");
    $cat->execute();
    $row_cat = $cat->rowCount();
    return $row_cat;
}
```

Then in order to retrieve data on screen, I did this:

```
$tagSet = new Blogs();
$tags = $tagSet->NumTag();
$tagShow = $tagSet->ShowTag();

if(!empty($tags)){
    $tagShow->GetTags();
}else{
    echo "There is no tag available right now!";
}
```

But the problem is I get this error message:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function GetTags() on null in line 20

Which is this line:

```
$tagShow->GetTags();
```

So what is the mistake with that ? Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the class function is

```
$tagShow = $tagSet->ShowTag(); //returns no value, hence $tagShow is null/empty.
```

Moreover,

```
$tagShow->GetTags();
```

GetTags() is a function which does not exist in your class. Also, you are calling the function wrong way. $tagShow is originally not an object of your class, it is a variable storing output from ShowTag().

If you have a function named GetTags(), call it using

```
$tagSet->GetTags();
```

Try using it this way:

```
public function ShowTag()
{
    $blog_tags=array();
    $tag = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT blog_tags FROM blogs");
    $tag->execute();
    while($row = $tag->fetch())
    {
        $blog_tags[] = $row['blog_tags'];
    }

    return $blog_tags;
}
```

and then in your calling,

```
$tagShow = $tagSet->ShowTag();

if(count($tagShow)>0){
    print_r($tagShow);   //Do whatever with the tags array.
}else{
    echo "There is no tag available right now!";
}
```

Try this way and see if it helps.

Comment: Then it shows nothing, no output and no error! However there are some rows existing in db!

Comment: Did you add the getTags() function in the class. If yes, please update your code so I can check. Also, try returning something from ShowTags() and print it and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did all the steps that you've said, still shows nothing, I have also updated question and added the `GetTags()` method.

Comment: OOPS! Right now I got you :) , THANKS!

Comment: @rapaistaliol: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

here your code:

```
  if(!empty($tags)){

    $tagShow->GetTags();

  }else{
    echo "There is no tag available right now!";
  }
```

there `GetTags()` function isn't this current class. if GetTags in this class so use `$this->GetTags()` .